# Local Server connection to internal Mail-Server and SSL

Tags: ssl, email, docker, internal-dns

I work in a company that has a pretty strict policy regarding the separation of internal and internet. I got a server for our branch office, I have a static IP for our internal network but no domain. Unfortunately, it is not possible to enter a domain in the company DNS server. I currently have some Docker containers running on the server. I have a few questions about this.

1. we actually use a Mattermost container for our local communication, unfortunately I don't see how I can create a self singned certificate for this server to be able to use TLS because i just have an IP-Adress and not a domain.
2. i would also like to be able to send mails to our internal mail server so that my colleagues can register themselves on the services by e-mail address. Am I right in thinking that I need an SMTP relay that forwards the mails to the internal mail server? What is the best way to implement this and can I only run it on the IP?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to send mail you first need to make sure if you connect to the internal mail server on the smtp ports.

Then you have either two choices:

1. You could setup a mail server in a docker container where the other containers can connect to and forwards/relays the mail to the internal mail server. This of course requires some knowledge of howto setup a Mailserver
2. You request to whom manages the internal Mailserver if he can allow to send mail using an smtp client service in your applications
3. You use a cloud mail service like sendgrid

You can create a self signed certificate using openssl. Using a self signed certificate is not very secure but ok. Many tutorials online how to generate a self signed certificate using openssl